# Защита доступа по паролю

Tags: безопасность, пароль

я вот тут придумал.

1)  пароль лежит в **файле** в зашифрованом виде

2) здесь мы получаем из файла даннные

3) затем расшифровываем данные и сравниваем с введенным паролем

4) если пароль верный пользователю предлагается ввести **новый** пароль для следующего запуска программы и запомнить его

5) если пароль неверный тут подключайте вашу фантазию

6) теперь полученный **новый** пароль шифруем и снова перезаписываем в этот же **файл**

вопрос: сможет ли злоумышленник взломать такой алгоритм?

Comment: лучше сделайте с ключом на rassbery-pi  или irda брелке. алгоритм авторизации - что нить типа SSL с ключами DSA 4096,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот способ не очень надёжен.

Его слабое место — проверка проводится лишь один раз и на машине, полностью подчинённой пользователю. Это значит, что если злонамеренный пользователь при помощи отладчика найдёт в вашей программе проверку (сравнение паролей), осуществляемую в пункте 4, и заменит условный переход на безусловный, программа будет работать с любым паролем. Упс.

С другой стороны, станьте на позицию честного пользователя. Ему необходимо каждый раз придумывать пароль и запоминать его. Либо он будет использовать один и тот же пароль, либо будет придумывать плохие пароли. (Придумать и запомнить хороший пароль нелегко, а уж делать это каждый день вообще невозможно.) Или рисковать забыть пароль и не иметь возможности запустить программу больше.

Обратите внимание, что вообще не существует надёжных методов защиты приложения, бегущего на машине злонамеренного пользователя, так как машина (а значит, и ваш процесс) полностью находится под его контролем. Вы можете лишь немного усложнить задачу взлома.

Если безопасность действительно важна, пусть защищаемая часть бежит как веб-сервис и не будет доступна пользователю.

Comment: Зачем "злонамеренному пользователю" иметь дело с дебаггером, если хэш пароля лежит в файле, "вычилить" расположение которого можно и без дебаггера?

Comment: @0xFFh: Ну, хэш пароля ещё надо обратить, а здесь можно и не суметь для хорошего алгоритма криптографического хеширования. Хотя, у ТС расшифровка производится по факту без ключа :-) Но всё равно, алгоритм расшифровки надо ещё отыскать при помощи отладчика, а если уж мы взяли отладчик в руки, легче не вытаскивать алгоритм, а найти тот самый `jne`.

Comment: Если безопасность действительно важна, пусть защищаемая часть бежит как веб-сервис и не будет доступна пользователю. @vladD где про это почитать можно или на пальцах объясните.

Comment: Где почитать, и правда не знаю. Смотрите. Если программа бежит на сервере и доступна, например, через браузер, то никакой злонамеренный пользователь не сможет узнать пароль, не (а) добравшись до сервера, или (б) перехватив соединение другого пользователя. От (б) можно избавиться с помощью криптографии, от (а) просто не пуская на сервер никого (и не запуская других, взламываемых сервисов на этом сервере). Вот так вкратце.

Comment: "алгоритм расшифровки надо ещё отыскать". Основополагающий принцип Кирхгофа учит нас, что алгоритм должен быть открытым. Стойкость криптозащиты должна зависеть только от ключа

Comment: @renegator: если руководствоваться этим принципом, стойкость вообще нулевая: расшифровка пароля выполняется фиксированным алгоритмом.

Answer (score 1):

Взломать можно все, особенно такой нехитрый способ смены пароля. Во многом успешность "безболезненного" взлома зависит от сложности алгоритма шифрования пароля. Так, с алгоритмом base64, например, велика вероятность, что вас хакнут( по известным причинам ), с MD5 - вероятность близка к нулю.

*Да и вообще, с паролями как обычно поступают:* хранят их хэш, а сам пароль известен лишь его создателю. А при вводе пароля сверяют не первоначальный набор символов, а хэши.

Хэши, правда, если их хранить в открытом виде в файле, тоже можно легко подменить и поломать тем самым всю систему безопасности, так что позаботьтесь о безопасности своего приложения.

Comment: значит все упирается в стойкости шифрования?

значит в моем алгоритме надо шифровать с помощью md5.

по мне так лучше пусть систему безопасности поломают чем получат доступ к данным или вы другого мнения?

Comment: против вашего способа есть кейлоггер, как вы от него защититесь?

Comment: Наверняка, если вашу систему безопасности "проломят", то затем будет следовать получение данных из самой системы. Вам не обязательно использовать именно MD5, главное, чтобы алгоритм был необратимым( MD-подобные алгоритмы в этом числе ). Base64 - обратимый( т.е можно получить первоначальный набор символов ). Также необходимо позаботиться о сокрытии самого хэша пароля.

Comment: ну спрятали вы хеш очень хорошо, затем проломили вам систему и засунули вам кейлоггер. и получили пароль считав его с ваших пальцев, затем с помощью вашего пароля свободно зашли в вашу систему и получили полный доступ к вашей программе.

в моем случае пароль одноразовый, его считали кейлогером а повторно этот пароль не действует. остается только одно дизасемблирование самого exe файла, вот тут я слаб

Comment: Смотрим пункт 4 вашего плана: 

> если пароль верный пользователю предлагается ввести новый пароль для следующего запуска программы и запомнить его

То есть, кейлоггер спокойно сможет прочитать новый пароль. Теперь безопасность данных пользователя зависит лишь от того, кто раньше залогинится с новым паролем - пользователь или злоумышленник.

---

То что вы слабы в дизассемблировании, не значит, что хакеры слабы. В большинстве приложений защита сводится к однократной проверке введённого пароля и принятии решения о лицензионности программы. Саботировать эту проверку - легче лёгкого.

Comment: а если перед вводом нового пароля просто пошаманить клавишами на пустом месте или рандомно сэмулировать нажатия по клавишам, как кейлоггер среагирует на это?